# How to add staggered item entrance animation to WinUI ItemsRepeater?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui

ItemsControl has an `ItemContainerTransitions` property that supports `<EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="True" />`. I want to move to ItemsRepeater for its improved performance with large lists. But ItemsRepeater doesn't seem to provide any bulit-in functionality similar to `EntranceThemeTransition`. Anyone know how I might achieve a similar animation effect for ItemsRepeater?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, there only is a preview API without documentation. You can take a look at the WinUI's MUXControlsTestApp that implemented some examples of using the ElementAnimator to create animations here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/main/dev/Repeater/TestUI/Samples/AnimationSamples